# Unit Test Case Error For Observer Class Sales Order

Tags: magento-community, magento2.4.5, unit-tests

**Hi
Can anyone help me on this. I have created the unit test for the observer class sales order . When I am running the Unit test I am getting below error I tried but didn't get any solution**.

> There was 1 error: 1)
> VendorName\ModuleName\Test\Unit\Observer\SalesOrderPlacedAfterObserverTest::testExecute
> Error: Call to a member function getId() on null
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/VendorName/magento-module-ModuleName/src/Observer/SalesOrderPlacedAfterObserver.php:45
> /var/www/html/vendor/VendorName/magento-module-ModuleName/src/Test/Unit/Observer/SalesOrderPlacedAfterObserverTest.php:84
>
> ERRORS! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

## Main Observer Class

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Queue as QueueHelper;
use VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Connection as SFMCHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Manager;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderPlacedAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var QueueHelper
     */
    protected QueueHelper $queueHelper;

    /**
     * @var SFMCHelper
     */
    protected SFMCHelper $sfmcHelper;

    /**
     * @param SFMCHelper  $sfmcHelper
     * @param QueueHelper $queueHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        SFMCHelper  $sfmcHelper,
        QueueHelper $queueHelper
    ) {
        $this->sfmcHelper = $sfmcHelper;
        $this->queueHelper = $queueHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Order save after event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $lastOrderId = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
        $orderId = $lastOrderId->getId();
        if ($orderId && $this->sfmcHelper->isAutoSyncEnabled()) {
            $this->queueHelper->publishSFMCMessage($orderId, QueueHelper::SFMC_EVENT_ORDER_UPDATE);
        }
    }
}
```

## Unit Test Class

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Test\Unit\Observer;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Framework\Event;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\SalesOrderPlacedAfterObserver;
use VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Connection as SFMCHelper;
use VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Queue as QueueHelper;

class SalesOrderPlacedAfterObserverTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var SalesOrderPlacedAfterObserver
     */
    protected $salesorderplacedafterObserver;

    /**
     * @var SFMCHelper
     */
    protected $sfmcHelper;

    /**
     * @var QueueHelper
     */
    protected $queueHelper;

    /**
     * @var Observer
     */
    protected $observer;

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp(): void
    {

        $this->observer = $this->createMock(Observer::class);
        $this->_eventMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Event::class)
            ->addMethods(['getOrder', 'getId'])
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $this->observer->expects($this->any())->method('getEvent')->willReturn($this->_eventMock);

        $this->sfmcHelper = $this->createMock(SFMCHelper::class);
        $this->queueHelper = $this->createMock(QueueHelper::class);
        $this->salesorderplacedafterObserver = new SalesOrderPlacedAfterObserver(
            $this->sfmcHelper,
            $this->queueHelper
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExecute()
    {
        $orderId = '1';

        $orderMock = $this->createPartialMock(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::class,
            ['getId']
        );
        $this->_eventMock->expects($this->once())->method('getOrder')->willReturn($orderMock);
        $orderMock->expects($this->once())->method('getId')->willReturn($orderId);


        // I assume this value should be true
        // Implement to fit you method return value
        $this->sfmcHelper->expects(self::once())
            ->method('isAutoSyncEnabled')
            ->willReturn(true);

        // Can be useless depend on your method utility
        $this->queueHelper->expects(self::once())
            ->method('publishSFMCMessage')
            ->with($orderId, QueueHelper::SFMC_EVENT_ORDER_UPDATE);

        $this->salesorderplacedafterObserver->execute($this->observer);
    }
}
```